# How to print .dwg to .pdf with teigha true view

Tags: dwg

I don't have Autocad software and I can only find this free tool which can't read .dwg files.

Now, I need to convert .dwg to .pdf. But the `teigha true view` can't export .dwg

to .pdf.  But I find it offers a plot command. Unfortunately, I aslo don't have the

DWF6 ePlot.pc3 printer. So, does anyone know how to handle that or is that an impossible

task?  Do you know any other software can convert .dwg to .pdf?

Comment: what is your AutoCAD version?

Comment: @vinayan I don't install autocad. Can I do that without autocad.

Comment: oh..i didn't read the post carefully..Do you have AutoCAD? its much easier then..

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried any of these, but a simple [Google search](http://www.google.com.au/search?hl=en&qscrl=1&nord=1&rlz=1T4ADRA_enAU429AU430&q=dwg%20to%20pdf&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&biw=1920&bih=871&wrapid=tlif134129722408910&um=1&ie=UTF-8&sa=N&tab=iw&ei=EJPyT9LAIYefiAeD95DfAw) yielded these:

- http://anydwg.com/dwg2pdf/
- http://download.cnet.com/AutoDWG-DWG-to-PDF-Converter/3000-6677_4-10256832.html
- http://www.convertfiles.com/convert/document/DWG-to-PDF.html

That last one looks like you need to upload the file to their server which may have issues if the file is big.  It may have privacy implications.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I need a free solution and better run in command line or embeded my application. I have consider your search result. they all need to pay money and may not support all .dwg version. I think teigha tools is the best solution

Answer (score 3):

`Autodesk DWG TrueView` is a  a free stand-alone .dwg viewer with DWG TrueConvert software included. It includes PDF plotters so you can directly plot to pdf. This would be the most reliable option.

you can download from [Autodesk Website](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/pc/item?siteID=123112&id=9078813)

There is a Plot/Batch Plot option too

[image]

Comment: Great, That is what I need. Another question. How can I call `Autodesk DWG TrueView` in java to plot.

Comment: @pythonee - don't think there is any API for automation..But you can batch plot to pdf

Answer (score 2):

IrfanView is free and has a variety of plugins. You can read a DWG and write to PDF. Also, IrfanView has a commandline interface. If this doesn't open the latest DWG version, you can convert your DWG to an older version using Teigha File Converter. I think this has a command line option, as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can also upload your dwg to https://www.autocadws.com en convert it from there (use the "download" button).
You can definitely upload to autocadws using webdav, not sure if the conversion can be applied from the api. Have a look at: 
http://www.autocadws.com/tutorials/autocad-ws-apis-c-client/

One advantage is that autocad ws can handle whatever dwg format out there, so your application will still support dwgs made in 2015, when the format will probably change again.

Answer (score 0):

[dwg to pdf](http://www.pdftoflashconverter.com/dwg-to-pdf.htm)

or with more online converter 
https://cloudconvert.com helps convert dwgtopdf document